# API Authorization Allowing Public Create Actions Risks?

Tags: javascript, python, api, security

I want to know if what I'm proposing is a typical scenario for the system I have or something I should be concerned about in regards to the API security.

The system is a small widget that can be placed on any site allowing members to be added via an API to one of my users campaigns.

```
Member Name
Member ID
Who the Member belongs to (user ID)
```

I have an API resource called members. Each member belongs to a user of my system.

I have created Authorization like in the table below . **Note:** By authorization I mean "is permission granted for this user to take this action" and not to be confused this with **authentication** i.e. access to the API):

```
==============  =======  =======  =======  =======
Resource        Create   Read     Update   Delete
==============  =======  =======  =======  =======
Member          Public   Owner    Owner    No
==============  =======  =======  =======  =======
```

By public I mean **ANY** one can create a new member no matter who there are. However, once this record is created only the owner (the user it was created for) can read or update it.

I don't see how anyone gets around this issue of the **create** record being public as this happens via a **javascript** external to my site which I have no control over (client side). There is no way for me to know who there are. However, doing anything with that member after requires the user to login to my site and control is gained.

What I could see happening is lots of fake members being created for my users but I see no way of this being prevented

Would anyone do this different or I'm I over thinking this?

**Note:** Python Tag added because it's a Python API and maybe this makes a difference or not. Javascript tag added as the client side is script. If not or off topic I'm remove the tag or question.

Comment: If your only option is to create the members via client side, then I think your choice is alright.
You just need to restrict the amount of users that can be created from the same IP and delete those who didn't login within 48-72 hours.

At least that's what I'd do. Run a cron job that deletes all those who never logged within certain amount of time (probably fake member) and restrict the amount of members per IP to, let's say - 10. That way you can't be spammed by a script kiddie via JS console, yet you give an ability to people in the same network (IP) to create few accounts if needed.

Comment: @Fratyr thanks for the reply. It's the only option I can think of to be honest but I'm open to other suggestions. Authenticating an anonymous user is really what I'm asking, but then whats the point in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system doesn't have any inherent flaws in it, but it isn't impossible to circumvent. For example, if someone is good, they can fake an ip address, so it would be possible to make multiple accounts from one computer if all you look at is the ip address. It would be difficult to prevent multiple accounts if the person can use false identification, but you could maybe try to identify activity or lack of it that could signal a fake user. Probably the best way to combat security problems with fake users is to make a user have to give information like an email address as well, and limit the number of users under one email address. This should significantly slow any problems. If you make them "jump through the hoops", it becomes more difficult to fake and easy to trace if someone tries to fake accounts. If you want users to be more anonymous, anything that makes it impossible to create or manage users electronically would help a lot, so something like a captcha would help.